# What for is new keyword is used in C# before attribute class name?

Tags: c#, class, attributes, new-operator

What is the purpose of the C# `new` keyword when used before an attribute class name?

I am using Rider and it suggests to place a new keyword before attribute names pretty often.

```
public class MyClass
{
   new AttributeClass attribute;

   ...    
}
```

Comment: Can you perhaps explain where Rider suggests doing this, as it doesn't achieve anything in this specific example.  Stating `new` before a property would be used for hiding the same property in a base class, but I don't see any use here

Comment: Please clarify exactly what code is resulting in the suggestion.  Then maybe someone can help you with a definite answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As explained in documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/versioning-with-the-override-and-new-keywords):

> If the method in the derived class is preceded with the new keyword, the method is defined as being independent of the method in the base class.

`new` keyword on an attribute will let you overwrite type of it. Object when viewed as the base type will not know about it. It can also have a different value in base type and derived type of the same object instance. Needles to say, that can lead to some very confusing bugs.

Consider this example:

```
class Super
{
    int Id;
}

class Sub : Super
{
    new string Id;
}

static class Another
{
    static void AssignId(Super test, int val)
    {
        test.Id = val;
    }

    static Super ShowId(Super test)
    {
        return test.Id;
    }
}
```

...

```
var test = new Sub
{
    Id = "SUB123"
};

Another.AssignId(test, 123);
Console.WriteLine(Another.ShowId(test)); // 123
Console.WriteLine(test.Id); // SUB123
```

Answer (score 2):

The other posters have explained what the keyword means.

It's not 100% clear from the question but the op may have been asking why it is being suggested in this particular case.

Refactoring tools would suggest you use the new keyword when they detect that you have implemented a member in a derived class that has the same name as a virtual member in the base class.

When this happens you have some choices.

Either use the override keyword if the intention is to extend the base class functionality.

Or, use the new keyword if you want to replace the base implementation entirely.

Or, rename the member in the derived class if the naming clash is just a co-incidence.

I deleted this post and then un-deleted it as I can't make up my mind if the question is even answerable with the information given.  I am assuming that the op is talking about being prompted to use the new keyword when declaring members on a derived type.  If they were trying to instantiate a reference type without using the new keyword they would get a compiler error; not a suggestion...  But then again who knows from the example given.

Answer (score 0):

The `new` keyword on a class property is used when replacing an overridable property from a base class.

E.g.

```
void Main()
{
    var objA = new Base {
        Prop = "test"
    };

    var objB = new Derived {
        Prop = 42
    };
}
public class Base
{
    public virtual string Prop { get; set; }
}
public class Derived : Base
{
    public new int Prop { get; set; }
}
```

[Read more...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords)